# How can set Table to fit cover in div Size in react useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rxjs

Table set to the `div` size how can do that please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeWzH.png)

On that Image I can share how can set table I the `div`.`

Here I is my `useEffect` what is my mistake; me help me with that.

```
const [heights, setHeights] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
    const otherDivs =
      document.querySelector('.header').offsetHeight +
      document.querySelector('.products_head').offsetHeight +
      document.querySelector('.products_active-filters').offsetHeight +
      document.querySelector('.pagination').offsetHeight +
      (document.querySelector('.my_list-body').innerHeight -
        document.querySelector('.my_list-body').clientHeight);
    setHeights(window.innerHeight - otherDivs - 10);
  }, []);

return(
      <div className="my_list-body order_table" style={{ heights }} >
)
```

this can not work in my project

I can not get with CSS Only with `useEffect`

Answer (score 1):

The `style` prop should be:

```
style={{height: `${heights}px`}}
```

not `style={{heights}}`

Comment: No i can define useState as a heights that's why use heights

Comment: Sorry, updated my code; the `style` property should be named `height`

Comment: not work this code